# Facebook integration in not working if native facebook app is installed android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using user registration in my app through facebook, its working fine if Facebook Native App is not installed on mobile. As Facebook Native App is already installed On mobile then it doesn't open Facebook login dialog box. Please anybody know a solution?

Comment: If you use the official Facebook SDK, it should open the Facebook app if present, or as a fallback, open a full-screen WebView. What you describe is strange. Please clarify, tell us which SDK you're using (which version also) and expose some code.

Comment: Hi Amit, have you identified the problem yet? yet? @shkschneider I have the same issue it seems. I'm using 4.3. Somehow when I log out of my native fb app and tries to fb login with my dev app, it will switch to my native app prompting for a login. After I logged in, I'll be redirected to the Web dialog for permissions again. Other times, I'll just be shown the Web dialog. Appreciate any advice. I've checked my key hash is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your aps key hash to facebook developer console of the id you are using for Facebook inside app. Here is a picture, where you should put your things:

[image]

To get the debug key hash create a GoogleMap activity, and it will automatically create res file - google_maps_api.xml, inside it use the key untill ";" symbol:

[image]

And put it inside this webpage(not mine) and use Output (base64), that is the key-hash you need - http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php